# How to insert a row having only one column different than the other row in the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I want to insert the new rows into my data table which is having only one column different as compared to the other columns in the existing rows

For e.g.:
Existing rows in the **`XYZ` table**:

```
No  Name        Model
90  Kolkata     ABC
90  Bangalore   ABC
90  Mumbai      ABC
```

Rows I want to insert into the **same table**:

```
No  Name        Model
70  Kolkata     ABC
70  Bangalore   ABC
70  Mumbai      ABC
```

Note: There is no primary key or a foreign key in this table

Please anyone can help me with the insertion query with which I can replace only one column and insert the new data

Comment: What if you have a row `(90,'Mumbai','XYZ')` you still want to add a new row corresponding to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO xyz
SELECT      70, name, model
FROM        xyz
WHERE       no = 90
```